# Spring Controller mapping using regex

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting a following GET request
http://localhost:8080/flamingo-json/en/web/Mobile/our-program/Tiers-recognition-Redesigned/rewards-program-new.html

For the above url I have defined the following Mapping in spring rest controller

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/flamingo-json/{language}/{platform}/{page:.+}")
@ResponseBody
public String getAboutUs(@PathVariable(value = "language", required = false) String language,@PathVariable String platform,
                         @PathVariable String page){
    logger.info("Serving " + page + " page for the request");
    return aboutUsService.getPageFromDb(page, language, platform);
```

but I am unable to get "Mobile/our-program/Tiers-recognition-Redesigned/rewards-program-new.html" value in the Path variable 'page' and I am getting 404.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to jump to other page, delete the annotation `@ResponseBody`;if you want to get the value(like json) from this request,change the annotation to `@PostMapping`. hope the ans works.

Comment: I have removed the @ResponseBody but still I am getting 404, also I have thymeleaf templates, I just want to return string instead of thymeleaf template

Comment: you can debug this request, judge whether to enter the request. if can enter the request, try to change the `@getmapping` to the `@postmapping`.  if not ,maybe regex not in effect.  i guess. sorry,I know little about regex.